# Creating a list of links with a loop in wicket

Tags: java, html, list, loops, wicket

I am new to Wicket, so I'm not sure if this is a stupid question or not, either way, I couldn't find an answer by googling a lot and searching on stackoverflow.

I'm trying to create an html list of links generated by the contents of an arraylist. This list may vary in size, so I can't create static links, they have to be generated by a loop. The list is on my HomePage.html and I want all these links to refer tot OtherPage.html, but with different parameters. The link should have the same name as the parameter "name" I'm passing through. 
My 'try' is as following: (I'm using generic names here to keep things simple)

```
RepeatingView list = new RepeatingView("list");
for (final String s : names) {
 Link l = new Link("link") {
  @Override
  public void onClick() {
   PageParameters pageParameters = new PageParameters();
   pageParameters.add("name", s);
   setResponsePage(OtherPage.class, pageParameters);
  }
 };
 l.setBody(Model.of(s));
 list.add(new Label(list.newChildId(), l));
}
add(list);
```

This the html part that I thought would be needed:

```
<ul>
 <li wicket:id="list"></li>
</ul>
```

I did another attempt using ListView with no success

```
List<String> namesList = Arrays.asList();
for (String s : names) {
    namesList.add(s);
}
add(new ListView<String>("names", namesList) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(final ListItem<String> item) {
        Link l = new Link("name") {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                PageParameters pageParameters = new PageParameters();
                pageParameters.add("name", item.getModel());
                setResponsePage(PatternPage.class, pageParameters);
            }
        };
        l.setBody(Model.of(item.getModel()));
        item.add(l);
    }
});
```

with the following html:

```
    <div id="bd" style="display: table;">
        <div wicket:id="names" style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
            <div wicket:id="name" style="display: table-cell;"></div> </div>
    </div>
```

it resulted in this error:

```
Last cause: null
WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public paf.assignment3.HomePage(org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters)' and argument ''. An exception has been thrown during construction!
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it working. I had to add the link to the list and leave out the labels.
Here's the java code. First I used a loop for adding all links.

```
    RepeatingView list = new RepeatingView("list");
    for (final String s : names) {
        list.add(createLink(list.newChildId(), s));
    }
    add(list);
```

I made a separate method for creating the links itself, to keep a clean code. Here's the method createLink:

```
    public Link createLink(String linkName, final String name) {
        Link l = new Link(linkName) {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
            PageParameters pageParameters = new PageParameters();
            pageParameters.add("name", name);
            setResponsePage(PatternPage.class, pageParameters);
        }

    };
    l.setBody(Model.of(name));
    return l;
}
```

The html stayed like this:

```
    <ul>
        <li wicket:id="list"></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `setResponsePage(OtherPage.class, pageParameters)` you page class has to have a constructor with PagaParameter argument.

Or just use `setResponsePage(new OtherPage(name))` instead.

Comment: It's not OtherPage that isn't working. It's the HomePage that's not working, because of the list I'm trying to make. If I remove the code for creating the list, the page works just fine. I tried adding a static link to OtherPage with working parameters, which resulted in HomePage and OtherPage displaying as they should.